# What does it mean when someone's comments invalidate their question (or answer)

Tags: discussion

Does it suggest they are using a chat bot or that their question was just random noise or what exactly?

I'm guesisng it could well be the former and they aren't great with chat-gpt, that they are asking the app questions from, rather than about, its previous responses, if that makes sense. But IDK

[Is the speciousness of the specious present specious?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/105438/is-the-speciousness-of-the-specious-present-specious)

> what about events that are viewed from a different location from their
> origin? Is having a time extended word in Experience much different
> from having a simultaneous view in Experience?
>
> [image]
>
> When we have Experience it is like a view, it occurs around a centre
> point (although nothing flows into that point in the view). There is
> separation of the centre from the periphery.

I was unsure what the argument was, and they explained

> a time extended object in our Experience is always fixed at the same
> place in space. Remove this assumption by permitting motion or a
> flexible geometry and it is possible to have an ersatz time extension,
> represented by a pattern in space, or a real time extension that uses
> a flexible, non-Euclidean geometry

Which surely isn't what appears in the original question. An example from a few accoounts.